# Fetching name based on id in ajax

Tags: ajax, jsp

In the console,I am getting name based on id.How to bind that name into the html page.

Here is my code..

```
function getEventname(){

  var clid=$('#eventid').val();
  console.log("i am ok" + clid);

  $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "EduManage.jsp",
      data: {
        control:'ajax', 
        ch:'1', 
        key:'1_0a1m_1', 
        eventid:clid
      },
      success: function(data) {
         console.log("i am ok" + data);
         (what to do to bind the name in the html page)
      }
  });

}
```

Now the HTML is;

```
<td class="bg1">
    Event Id :
</td>
<td class="bg1" width="25%">
    <input name="eventid" type="text" id="eventid" size="10" maxlength="10" onblur="getEventname()"/> 
</td>

<td class="bg1" width="40%"> 
     Event Name :
</td>
<td class="bg1" width="25%">
     <input type="text" name="eventname" id="eventname">
</td>
```

In the console,I am getting name as `i am ok seminar`  .How to bind that name in the HTML page automatically when id is given.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your Javascript function should be;

```
function getEventname(){

   var clid=$('#eventid').val();
   console.log("i am ok"+clid);

   $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "EduManage.jsp",
       data: {
         control:'ajax', 
         ch:'1', 
         key:'1_0a1m_1', 
         eventid:clid
       },
       success: function(data) {
               console.log("i am ok"+data);
               //The one line change
               $("#eventname").val(data);
       }
  });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you had already implemented everything. All you need to do is add data in some element. If you want to add it in td then use this:

```
$.ajax({type: "GET",url: "EduManage.jsp",data: {control:'ajax', ch:'1', key:'1_0a1m_1', eventid:clid},
                success: function(data) {
                console.log("i am ok"+data);
                $("td.last").append(data);
                (what to do to bind the name in the hmtl page)
                }
});
```

and add a new html tag:

```
<td class="last"></td>
```

You can also update the html using jquery but its not a practice to do so.

Hope this works.